# CakePHP join model and its own relationships

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.x

In `Shop` model I have:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Company' => array()
);
```

Model `Company` has its own relationships defined in its model class. How can I fetch `Company relation` when performing:

```
$this->Shop->find('all',
       array(
           'conditions' => array(
               'Shop.loyaltycard' => 0,
            )
       )
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have properly declared the relationships,`find()` will automatically fetch the first level of associated models, provided you haven't altered the default level of recursion (which is 1).

If it fails, try the following:

```
$this->Shop->recursive=1;
$this->Shop->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Shop.loyaltycard' => 0,
    )
));
```

More on Model attribute [`recursive`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#recursive).

Another option is to load the Containable behavior, which will allow you to filter which relationships you wish to fetch.

```
$this->Shop->Behaviors->load('Containable'); //or make your model act as Containable 
$this->Shop->contain('Company');
$this->Shop->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Shop.loyaltycard' => 0,
    )
));
```

More on [`ContainableBehavior`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

Also, please modify your relationship declaration to the following:

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Company'
);
```

Not sure how the empty array affects your relationship, but it may cause it to fail. Please note that this will only work if you have followed [CakePHP conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/getting-started/cakephp-conventions.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to find all related model but just Company you can add
`$actsAs = array('Containable');`
in your shop model and then do the search like this:

```
$this->Shop->find('all',array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'Shop.loyaltycard' => 0,
    ),'contain' => array(
         'Company'
));
```

See cakephp containable http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html